# Count record each day of a month from mysql into html table

Tags: html, mysql, count, html-table, record

I'd like to put all mySql results in a html table. This is mySql:

```
SELECT date(vwr_date) AS mon, date(vwr_date) AS date, count(vwr_cid) AS views 
FROM car_viewer 
WHERE Year(vwr_date)='2012' AND vwr_tid='18' 
GROUP BY date 
ORDER BY date DESC
```

From the query above, it results like this:

```
date        views
2012-10-23  14
2012-10-22  339
2012-10-21  305
2012-10-20  354
....
2012-10-01  291
2012-09-30  246
2012-09-29  297
...
2012-09-01  281
```

The result from mysql is very good. And now this is a problem. I tried many times and different ways to put those views into  according to each date from car_viewer.vwr_date. So I wrote like this:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" width="100%">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Mon Year / Date</th>
            <?
            for($i=1;$i<32;$i++){
                echo "<th>$i</th>";
            }
            ?>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?
        $_thisYear=date("Y");
        $sql_nViewer="select date(vwr_date) as mon, date(vwr_date) as date, count(vwr_cid) as views from car_viewer where Year(vwr_date)='$_thisYear' and vwr_tid='$_SESSION[admin_id]' GROUP BY date ORDER BY date desc";
        echo $sql_nViewer;
        $result_nViewer=mysql_db_query($dbname,$sql_nViewer);
        $rec_nViewer=mysql_fetch_array($result_nViewer);
        $_monYear=date("M Y",strtotime($rec_nViewer[mon]));
        $_monYear2=date("Y-n",strtotime($rec_nViewer[mon]));

            echo "<tr><td>$_monYear</td>";//month name
        $day=1;
        while($rec_nViewer=mysql_fetch_assoc($result_nViewer)){
            $_nViewerDBdate=$rec_nViewer['date'];
            $_nViewerDBviews=$rec_nViewer['views'];
            echo "
            <td>$_nViewerDBviews</td>
            ";$day++;
            if($day==$_daysInMon+1){
                echo "</tr>";
            }
        }
        ?>
        </tbody>
        </table>
```

The result of codes above is weird - not as what I want. I need the data to be displayed like this:
[image: expected table]

So please suggest what should I do to make it as I expected. Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can return data in that format from mysql

```
SELECT MONTH_v, YEAR_V
GROUP_CONCAT(IF(day_v=1, views, null)) AS '1',
GROUP_CONCAT(IF(day_v=2, views, null)) AS '2',
----
GROUP_CONCAT(IF(day_v=31, views, null)) AS '31'
FROM
(
 SELECT DAY(vwr_date) AS day_v, 
 MONTH(vwr_date) AS MONTH_v, 
 Year(vwr_date) AS YEAR_V,
 date(vwr_date) AS date_v, 
 count(vwr_cid) AS views 
 FROM car_viewer 
 WHERE Year(vwr_date)='2012' AND vwr_tid='18' 
 GROUP BY date_v 
)
GROUP BY MONTH_v, YEAR_V 
ORDER BY MONTH_v, YEAR_V DESC
```

Comment: I've got the error :
`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP_CONCAT(IF(day_v=1, views, null)) AS '1', GROUP_CONCAT(IF(day_v=2, views, n' at line 2`

Comment: Then I thought it might be some problem to the missing or over commas then I've got : `#1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias`